# Converting mysql data from hindi to english and dump data to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a form, which has 3 kind of user input -> English , Hindi, tamil

Now i am using separate table for each language, based on user selection form displays and he can fill the form in his regional language.

The only problem is now i want:

i have 3 tables which have 3 different lnaguages data like: english, hindi and tamil.

Now i want to provide app admin a link, using which he can get raw dump data of all 3 tables but in english only. Means converting data stored in hindi and marathi fonts on fly (i guess) to english and dump whole data in single 1 excel sheet.
 is it possible ? and if yes please provide some help.

Looking forward for some help thanks !

Comment: Is your Hindi table having column name in English or in Hindi?

Comment: You can get all Hindi or any other language data from mysql in to one page and just use Google translator to translate it in English. And not sure about how to get that data in Excel but you can still try http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24285/use-online-data-in-excel-2010-spreadsheets/

Comment: I have never tried using google translator to convert 2 different language on same page to 3rd language ever. Do you think that really gonna work (i will still try) And getting excel will not be a problem if i can get that 2 language converted.

Comment: Here try this website to translate your website in any language http://itools.com/tool/google-translate-web-page-translator